# Camera Orientation - HTML5

Tags: html, mobile, screen-orientation

I'm creating a mobile web application (HTML5/JavaScript/CSS only) that allows a user to take a picture.  The picture from the camera is then loaded into a `canvas` HTML element.  The user may rotate their phone when taking a photo so ultimately I want to rotate the output appropriately.  Is there a way in a web page only to determine which degree a user has rotated when taking a picture?  I'm not simply talking about whether they are in landscape mode.  I'm meaning if you hold your phone straight up in portrait mode face it down at your desk (its now parallel with your desk) and then rotate it to landscape.  This will not trigger an orientation change, but you will now be holding your phone in a "landscape" position if that makes sense.  This will be a common way users will be taking the photos.  I want to be able to rotate the image appropriately when uploading it.

Thank you

Comment: You may want to look at the [device orientation api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) if you want to handle this in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way in a web page only to determine which degree a user has rotated when taking a picture?

Yes there is!  When photos are taken, they contain metadata - information about the image.  This is called [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data.

It tells you things like the make of camera, whether the flash went off, and - usefully for you - the orientation of the camera.

If you are using JavaScript to draw the image onto the canvas, I can recommend [BlueImp's JavaScript Load Image Library](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image)

Once you have loaded the image, you'll be able to do a call like:

```
var orientation = data.exif.get('Orientation');
```

That will tell you which way the camera was held when the photo was taken.  Depending on the phone, you may also get rotation data, GPS data, compass heading, etc.